# Laravel Resource Call Relationship from other Relationship

Tags: laravel, api, resources

is there a way to get relationship of other relationship in Laravel resource?
I try something like this:

```
'customers' => $this->customers()->files()->get(),
```

I am actually inside Products. Products hasMany Customers and also Customers hasMany Files. What I'm trying to do is to get files of customer. Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
$this->customers()->with('files')->get()
```

Should work if proper relationships are setup.

**EDIT**:
The simplest solution to get count as well will be

```
$this->customers()->with('files')->withCount('files')->get()
```

Comment: Thank you, thats great. One more. How can I count files of this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming these are your models

```
class Products extends Model
{
    public function customers(){
     return $this->hasMany(Customers::class, 'product_id');
    }
}

class Customers extends Model
{
    public function files(){
     return $this->hasMany(Files::class, 'customer_id');
    }
}
```

To access all the files of one customer ($this is product)

```
$customers = $this->customers;
foreach($customers as $customer){
 $file = $customer->files;
}
```

If you want to access all the files of all the customers you can add another method to your Product model like below and $files = $product->files

```
class Products extends Model
{
    public function customers(){
     return $this->hasMany(Customers::class, 'product_id');
    }

    public function files(){
     return $this->hasManyThrough(Files::class, Customers::class);
    }
}
```